# why input|file can not assign their property "files" to variable in ie?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-io

I know the files property is read only. but why could not assign this property to another variable? it works in firefox, but not ie.

My code is:

```
    var element=document.getElementById("fileinput");
    var files=document.getElementById("fileinput").files;
    alert(element);    //here can output HTTPInputElement
    alert(files);      //but here is always undefined in ie;
```

I do not know why the four line always give me undefined in ie.
How can I get the filelist object from input|files as variable in ie?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 and below don't have a files property because they only accept one file at a time.

[IE: input type="file" multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085171/ie-input-type-file-multiple)

IE10 is supposed to add actual support, I have not tested it yet.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772931(v=vs.85).aspx In their example they have multiple property.

Comment: @user504909 Yes, but it is nevertheless an HTML5 feature and isn't supported until IE10: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10009206/1217408

Comment: The File API is a specification of its own, not part of HTML 5. Support for the multiple attribute is a feature separate to the File API.

Comment: @Quentin Then why does the microsoft page that the OP just commented have a section titled "Standards information" with a link to http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/ and have the HTML5 tag? I was just basing my conclusion on that, if it's wrong then so be it. My answer is still correct, though not as informative as yours :O

Comment: @TheZ — If you follow the links through, they leave the HTML 5 spec and go to the File API spec.

Comment: @Quentin That makes sense, I'll keep that in mind for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `files` property is part of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) which is still a draft specification and is [not supported by IE 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=file+api).

[Experimental support](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5labs/prototypes/fileapi/fileapi/info/) is in the IE 10 platform preview.

The problem is not that the property cannot be copied, but that it isn't defined in the first place.