# Multiple select in file upload not working in IE9

Tags: php

Hi am trying for multiple file select upload. I cant able to select multiple files in IE9. Chrome, safari, firefox working fine. I used this input tag to select multiple files.

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Comment: You can't do that directly in IE9 (or lower versions) until you use an appropriate jQuery plugin that enables it to upload multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only IE10 support this IE9 and older don't support. This question is similar as yours [IE: input type="file" multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085171/ie-input-type-file-multiple)