# HTML INPUT TYPE FILE MULTIPLE NOT WORKING IN IE

Tags: file-upload, html-input, multiple-file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files a t a time and used the following html code.

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple/>
```

It is working well in all other browsers except IE.I am using version 9 and above.If i want to make it work what are the changes required.Suggest please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple/>
```

> The multiple attribute is new in HTML5 ([Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp))

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) is a reference for `multiple`

```
Versions supporting `multiple` attribute

Chrome    Edge   Firefox   Opera   Safari
6.0       10.0   3.6       11.0    5.0
```

> Why it doesn't work with Internet Explorer ?

Uploading multiple files is a specific part of HTML5 that none of the Internet Explorers support. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7085229/9674579) is a reference to it. Though , IE 10.0 has started supporting it.

---

I found some related resources [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0e72657-962f-4254-b95c-c47482401899/multiple-file-uploading-in-ie9-and-older-versions?forum=ieextensiondevelopment) and [here](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/multiple-attribute/)

---

According to all above statistics , I might like to suggest you to read the second post of [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0e72657-962f-4254-b95c-c47482401899/multiple-file-uploading-in-ie9-and-older-versions?forum=ieextensiondevelopment) which uses certain alternatives of multiple attribute :

> If you can't or don't want to use multiple INPUT TYPE=FILE controls, you must use Flash or Silverlight or a custom ActiveX control

Comment: Thank u @Master Daark Night

Comment: Welcome @SRI , hope it helps you , and if it helps you then kindly accept my answer :)